# Scopes within while loops

Tags: python-3.x, variables, while-loop, scope

```
from random import randint

isRunning =True

while isRunning:
    dice1 = randint(1,7)
    dice2 = randint(1,7)
    print("The first die landed on ℅d and the second landed on ℅d." ℅ (dice1,dice2))
   user_input = input("Contiue? Yes or No?\n>")

   if user_input == "Yes" or "yes":
        print("="*16)

   elif user_input == "No" or "no":
        isRunning = False
```

I feel like I'm making such a simple mistake and when I decided to look into global variables and what not it still doesn't help. Could anyone explain why the while loop doesn't terminate, although the variable was set to false.

Comment: Check your indenting.  It looks from what you've posted as though everything from "user_input = " down is indented differently to the 3 lines above it.  Python requires indenting to be 100% identical on each line.  (Although this may be just a transposition issue when posting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if user_input== "Yes" or "yes"` should be

`if user_input== "Yes" or user_input =="yes"`, alternatively it's equivalent to `if any(user_input==keyword for keyword in["Yes", "yes"]):`

your original if clause is splitting to
`if user_input=="Yes"` or `if "yes"` and `if "yes"` always true, therefore your if-elseif clause always go to if clause.

Comment: Thank you, This fixed my problem.

Comment: Don't know how, unfortunately.

Comment: Have to wait 4 minutes.

Comment: You can save even more space for Stack Overflow by flagging these common duplicate questions as duplicates. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for providing down-voting reason.